# difference between unitarily equivalent and unitarily similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the difference between **unitarily equivalent** and **unitarily similar** for two Matrixes؟

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. Although typically, many people reserve "unitarily equivalent" for operators in some abstract Hilbert space, and reserve "unitarily similar" for finite-dimensional linear operators represented by matrices. But in the cases in which the operators are matrices, unitarily equivalent and unitarily similar are the same notion.

Comment: @ Ben S - Thanks.